# Android IAB V3 - Not receiving signatures with real purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I can't receive any signature (form the Intent - "INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE") from the response from Google Play after I bought an object. I uploaded my apk, published then unpublished and tried to buy a real in-app object with my test account.
Everything goes all right and Google Play sends me purchase data (INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA) but the INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE is always empty.
Is it because my app is not published?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- You should have your app PUBLISHED as ALPHA TEST
- Go to your settings panel (from the left pan click on the gear icon), then assign a tester in "Gmail accounts with testing access"
- NOTE: the gmail test account should not be same as your developer account.
- Login onto your android device with the test account you just assigned
- Note that it should be the primary account on the android device, if it is a secondary account, it won't work
- Build a release/production version of the app, then upload and install it onto your real android device.
- Note that a debug release does not work. You have to export and sign your apk file to be able to make purchases.
- It's done!

Comment: Got it! The problem was that I had not my app published...
Thank you very much!!